# How can I copy a previous work order from dynamics and create a new one using Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to create a new work order from dynamics 365 using Visual Studio.

I have added in the Plugins and the variables.

Below is the code:

I want to create a new work order if the booking status is completed. I want to include the name of the work order, billing account, service account information, product type, work order type and get the details for the price list.
Also if a survey is populated then I want to copy the information across to the new work order. but this code below is giving me an error, when I try to complete the first part. Product type and create wo code lines are giving me an error, any help would be much appreciated.

```
try
{
    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        bookableResourceBooking = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
        brbReference = (EntityReference)bookableResourceBooking.ToEntityReference();
    }

    postImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
    Guid boo = postImage.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("bookableresourcebookingid");


    bookingStatus = postImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("bookingstatus").Name;
    if (bookingStatus == "Completed")
    {
        EntityCollection workorder = getWorkorder(service, postImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_workorder").Id.ToString());

        // create a new work order
        msdyn_workorder wo = new msdyn_workorder();
        //String guid = postImage.Id.ToString();
        //guid.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
        //wo.Id = new Guid(guid);

    
     
        wo.msdyn_name = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<string>("msdyn_name");
        wo.msdyn_BillingAccount = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_billlingaccount");
        wo.msdyn_ServiceAccount = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_serviceaccount");
        //wo.new_ProductType = (msdyn_workorder_new_ProductType?)workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_productype").Value;
        wo.msdyn_WorkOrderType = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_workordertype");
        wo.msdyn_PriceList = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("msdyn_pricelist");
        service.Create(wo);
```

I want to create a new work order containing all the information, when the booking status is set to completed.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with this code:

1. Code sample is incomplete, the second if and try aren't closed
2. You should provide more details:

- What Entity, Stage, Event is this registered on

3. You're building an entity reference with the target and a guid with the post image but they're unused.  the entity reference would serve your guid needs, because the target and post image would have the same GUID.
4. What does getWorkorder() do?  Is it retrieving a collection of Workorders where the ID is the Workorder in the BRB?  Than this won't be a collection as there can only be one Workorder with that ID.  This could be a simple service.retrieve vs service.retrievemultiple
5. There is not need to parse the product type.  GetAttributeValue will return an OptionsetValue.  `wo.new_ProductType = workorder[0].GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_producttype");` should work
6. You should really use a publisher with a unique prefix vs "new" or the default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/change-solution-publisher-prefix?view=op-9-1
7. I recommend you first try to have your plugin create a workorder without the mapped values.  This will ensure you know what you are doing and then you can start including the mapped data attribute by attribute to find out where your mapping may be causing issues.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for taking the time out to answer the question. The if and else statements are there but I didn't include them in the code above by the looks of it. I am trying to fetch a work order so this is where i'm using getWorkorder. If the booking status is set to completed then i want to create a new work order. The only issue I have is with the product type, I have tried it but it doesn't work. Also service.Create(wo) doesn't let me create a work order either which i'm guessing would be related to product type?

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Which table are you registering the plugin onto?  What event? Sync? Async?  Also please provide all the code, where is the getWorkorder code?  Please update your question with these details.  Also as I recommended, first attempt to create a work order with static data, then move onto creating it with the previous WOs data.  You have a few fundamental issues you need to resolve...